# neither python 3 nor python 2 works well on ubuntu 18.04 with repo?

Tags: 18.04, repository, python3, git, python-2.7

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to init this repo :

```
# repo init -u https://github.com/anbox/platform_manifests.git -b anbox
```

since I'm using this version of python :

```
# python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
```

it does not work. it says :

```
warning: Python 3 support is currently experimental. YMMV.
Please use Python 2.6 - 2.7 instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/repo", line 886, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/bin/repo", line 854, in main
    _Init(args, gitc_init=(cmd == 'gitc-init'))
  File "/usr/bin/repo", line 340, in _Init
    _CheckGitVersion()
  File "/usr/bin/repo", line 394, in _CheckGitVersion
    ver_act = ParseGitVersion(ver_str)
  File "/usr/bin/repo", line 364, in ParseGitVersion
    if not ver_str.startswith('git version '):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

so ok. I created a symlink to python 2.7 :

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
root@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/ziomario/Scrivania/Data/Nano/I9/anbox-work# python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
```

but even this time it does not work :

```
# repo init -u https://github.com/anbox/platform_manifests.git -b anbox
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
remote: Counting objects: 8, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (142/142)
remote: Total 142 (delta 64), reused 142 (delta 64)
Ricezione degli oggetti: 100% (142/142), 137.91 KiB | 4.18 MiB/s, done.
Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (64/64), completed with 14 local objects.
Da https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
   ceba2dd..323b113  main       -> origin/main
   b64bec6..511a0e5  stable     -> origin/stable
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13      -> v2.13
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.1    -> v2.13.1
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.2    -> v2.13.2
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.3    -> v2.13.3
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.4    -> v2.13.4
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.5    -> v2.13.5
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.6    -> v2.13.6
 * [nuova tag]       v2.13.7    -> v2.13.7
  File "/home/ziomario/Scrivania/Data/Nano/I9/anbox-work/.repo/repo/main.py", line 79
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what else I can do ?

Comment: It looks like what ever this is you are trying to do from github wants an older version of python. Python 3.6 is the default version that comes with Ubuntu 18.04/18.10 But the latest version is Python 3.8.20 Dec 2019

Comment: I tried a lot of versions of python. even the 2.6 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

After you have run the command under python2, there will be an update of the repo script available, capable of handling python3.  Its location is `.repo/repo/repo`, with respect to the directory where you executed the command.  Change your python version back to python3 and, in that folder, run :

```
.repo/repo/repo -u https://github.com/anbox/platform_manifests.git -b anbox
```

If not set, first set your git name and email or you run into new errors.